# Where to "splice in" 24v C wire with no control board for new smart thermostat

Tags: thermostat

Hoping someone out there is smarter than me.  Recently got the amazon smart thermostat and it requires a C wire.  Old thermostat did not.  I do have an unused wire from the air handler to the thermostat but since there is no control board, I've no idea where to connect the wire I'm going to use for C.  Pictures below including wiring diagram.  Anyone with some smarts willing to tackle this one??

https://ibb.co/zXS38zg
https://ibb.co/Gpnn5qR
https://ibb.co/kSBQSJZ
https://ibb.co/HG11Crf
https://ibb.co/ZNP6FVj
https://ibb.co/TkK1WFs
https://ibb.co/qjGLXSn

Thank you
Mr. Notmrsparky

Answer (score 2):

The wiring diagram indicates that there's a yellow wire coming off the transformer, going into a wire nut with a blue wire. That's your C. I've highlighted it in the image below.

[image]